# Inspecting Files in Partially-Unknown Paths

Tags: c#, .net

I have a need to inspect the size of a file (places.sqlite) under users' Firefox profile across multiple machines. Unfortunately, Firefox profile folders have random names (e.g. xtqdakil.default). My challenge is how to inspect a file under a partially-unknown path. Example paths from two of my own machines:

```
%APPDATA%\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\xtqdakil.default\places.sqlite
%APPDATA%\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\zvbw7yfc.default-1444842847322\places.sqlite
```

If there was a way to get as far as %APPDATA%\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\, then "drop down" a level, then inspect places.sqlite that would suit my needs perfectly.

Comment: Can't you just enumerate the directories in `%APPDATA%\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles`, enter them, and then search for the places file?

Comment: I see two possibilities: a) check all directories under %APPDATA%\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\, and b) find a way to determine this random name. Firefox needs to keep this name somewhere, otherwise it could not access the folder itself. But I assume the name is intentionally difficult to determine to make a request like yours difficult for malicious code. Hence, probably, you will have to use aopproach a).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do a pattern search like

```
Directory.GetFiles(@"%APPDATA%\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\", "places.sqlite", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
```

This will give you back a list of absolute path of all places.sqlite files in profiles folder.